# saving website styles in cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

everyone. I'm using a cookie to save my website color style. The user can change color in real time and it will saved into his cookies. Before his choice I set default css color style like this (my.css)

```
.color-changing{
    background-color: #43A047;
}
```

when you working you can choose the color with jquery,

```
var panel_theme = $(".color-changing");
    if ($.cookie('background-color')) {
        panel_theme.css("background-color", $.cookie('background-color'));   
    }
    $("#greenColor").click(function () {
        panel_theme.css('background-color', '#43A047');
        $.removeCookie('background-color');
        $.cookie('background-color', '#43A047', {expires: 1, path: '/'});
    });
    $("#redColor").click(function () {
        panel_theme.css('background-color', '#d32f2f');
        $.removeCookie('background-color');
        $.cookie('background-color', '#d32f2f', {expires: 1, path: '/'});
    });
```

The problem is that when you choose the color which is different from default color, with every page reload you will see  the  very fast flicker from default color to choosen.  How I can avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be first to use localStorage instead of cookie. Saves cookie payload that gets sent for each and every request made to server.

Then save the actual css declaration as a style tag so you can write it  in the head before the html has even finished loading. This will prevent any flicker as the style will already exist as html is rendered

Something like this before closing `<head>`:

```
<script>
var theme_style = localStorage && localStorage.getItem('theme_style');
if(theme_style){
   document.write(theme_style);
}
</script>
```

Then to set style:

```
function updateUserStyle(color){
    // create style tag
    var style = '<style id="user_style">.color-changing{background-color: '+color + ';}</style>';
    // see if user style tag already exists and replace
    var $currUserStyle =$('#user_style'); 
    if($currUserStyle.length){
       $currUserStyle.replaceWith(style); 
    }else{
        // if didn't exist add to head
        $('head').append(style);
    }
    // store active style
    localStorage.setItem('theme_style', style);

}
```

Usage

```
$("#redColor").click(function () {
    updateUserStyle('#d32f2f');
});
```

Comment: how I can save it on the client machine? It shouldn't depend on server. As a result I don't understand you meaning "localStorage". I can't save theme for every user it isn't rational using. Cause for every person in that case I should rewrite page.

Comment: that is user machine...it's part of browser

Comment: and how to save it without cookies? give me example please

Comment: example? I gave you the code to do it answer. What more example do you need? Did you try it?

Comment: I did this, but instead of localstorage I used cookies. Thanks!

Comment: why?...now you have the extra load for every request sending that cookie to server. localStorage is more efficient. Either way please accept answer if it helped you

Comment: I just don't understand how to save and get data into localstoarge.

Comment: Well it's quite easy to look it up , but I also already showed you how. read the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API